# Accessing DeviceActivity API through Flutter plugin

Tags: swift, flutter, flutter-plugin

I am trying to access Apple's the Screen Time API to get to the `DeviceActivityData`.
But man, it's hard!

On Android it's just:

```
val usage = Stats.getUsageMap(context, start, end)
```

done.

On iOS I have to do all kind of shenanigans with `Family Control` and `AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization`.  (this is working for me)

Are there any examples to look at to go from there?
In particular I am trying to access DeviceActivityData (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/deviceactivity/deviceactivitydata)

I got this, but it's not doing anything:

```
public class SwiftAppUsagePlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  
  //** boilerplate flutter plugin code removed for readability **//

  func startMonitoring() {
        let schedule = DeviceActivitySchedule(intervalStart: DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0), intervalEnd: DateComponents(hour: 23, minute: 59), repeats: true, warningTime: nil)
      
        let center = DeviceActivityCenter()
        do {
            try center.startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule)
            print ("Monitor started")
        }
        catch {
            print ("Could not start monitoring \(error)")
        }  
    }
}

extension DeviceActivityName {
    static let daily = Self("daily")
}
```